# Python - Creating a pdf with tables and table titles

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, fpdf

I am trying to use Python to create multiple pdf files each containing 3 tables (each with text wrapping within the cells as well as a title at the top of the table). I am having difficulty finding the perfect library to use.

The closest I have got is using the fpdf "multi_cell" function, and using a tutorial I got a script that looks like this:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf=FPDF(format='letter', unit='in')

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_font('helvetica','',10.0)

loremipsum_1 = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel ne quando dissentias. \
Ne his oporteat expetendis. Ei tantas explicari quo, sea vidit minimum \
menandri ea. His case errem dicam ex, mel eruditi tibique delicatissimi ut. \
At mea wisi dolorum contentiones, in malis vitae viderer mel.
"""

loremipsum_2 = """Vis at dolores ocurreret splendide. Noster dolorum repudiare \
vis ei, te augue summo vis. An vim quas torquatos, electram posidonium eam ea, \
eros blandit ea vel. Reque summo assueverit an sit. Sed nibh conceptam cu, pro \
in graeci ancillae constituto, eam eu oratio soleat instructior. No deleniti \
quaerendum vim, assum saepe munere ea vis, te tale tempor sit. An sed debet ocurreret \
adversarium, ne enim docendi mandamus sea.
"""

effective_page_width = pdf.w - 2*pdf.l_margin

pdf.multi_cell(effective_page_width, 0.15, "Test title")
pdf.ln(0.5)

ybefore = pdf.get_y()
pdf.multi_cell(effective_page_width/2, 0.15, loremipsum_1, 1)


pdf.set_xy(effective_page_width/2 + pdf.l_margin, ybefore)
pdf.multi_cell(effective_page_width/2, 0.15, loremipsum_2, 1)
pdf.ln(0.5)

pdf.output('multi_cell_adjacent.pdf','F')
```

This solution is really close to what I want because it has text wrapping and it allows me to put a title above the table. But I can't find any documentation on how to **set the cell height automatically**. In this example the two cell heights turn out to be different in the pdf because of the amount of text inside each one. I will be using this script to make many pdfs with unpredictable amounts of text in the cells of each table, so I would need the height to be determined automatically... Also whenever I try to add **more rows** to this table they just overlap with each other.

Anyone know know how to fix these 2 problems or any other way to get multiple tables that fit these conditions into a pdf? (Note: I am on Linux so I cannot create a docx first and convert it to pdf).

Answer (score 1):

```
def alarms_summary(self):
    PDF .set_font("Arial", size=8, style="B")
    PDF .cell(180, 4, 'ALARMS SUMMARY', 1, 0, 'L')
    PDF .Ln()
    alarms_summary_col_names = ["Alarm Time", "Description"]
    PDF .set_font("Arial", size=6, style="B")
    for col_name in range(Len(alarms_summary_col_names)):
        PDF .cell(30*3, 4*1, alarms_summary_col_names[col_name], 1,0, 'L')
    PDF .Ln()
    Alarm_Time_col_values=['22/06/2017 07:26:04','22/06/2017 08:50:26','22/06/2017 11:13:33']
    Description_col_values=['Low Air Pressure','LAP Overflow Station 1','LAP Overflow Station 1']
    alarms_summary=list(zip(Alarm_Time_col_values,Description_col_values))
    PDF .set_font("Arial", size=6)
    # alarms_summary = cur .fetch all()
    retrieved_pg_no = PDF .page_no()
    for alarm in alarms_summary:
        # print(alarm)
        for value in [alarm[1], alarm[0]]:
        #   print(PDF .page_no())  
            if PDF .page_no() == retrieved_pg_no:
                PDF .cell(30*3, 4*1, string(value), 1,0, 'L')
            else:
                PDF .Ln()
                count = 1.5
                for col_name in range(Len(alarms_summary_col_names)):
                
                    PDF .cell(30*3, 4*1, alarms_summary_col_names[col_name], 1,0, 'L')
                    count = 1.5
                PDF .Ln()
                PDF .cell(30*3, 4*1, Str(value), 1,0, 'L')
                retrieved_pg_no = PDF .page_no()
        PDF .Ln()
    PDF .Ln(6)
```

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.